# R custom build graphics font

Tags: r, graphics, fonts

After building from source and installing R 3.3.2 font of plots became ragged and greek letters were changed by latin (as shown in the pictures below). What could have caused it?

This is my configure summary:

```
R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /usr/local

  C compiler:                gcc  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       f95  -g -O2

  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:            g++  -std=c++11 -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:        gcc -g -O2 -fobjc-exceptions

  Interfaces supported:      X11
  External libraries:        readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, TIFF, NLS, cairo, ICU
  Options enabled:           shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes
```

Stock R version

[image]

Custom R version

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was in my locale settings. After I've set all locale settings to en_US.UTF-8, all font related problems disappeared.

**Edit**

Tested on two machines. It was exactly the problem.